# Froala WYSIWYG Editor - Asp.net MVC

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, editor, froala

I was used [Froala WYSIWYG Editor](https://froala.com/wysiwyg-editor). Uploaded Images was successfully save in correct path but doesn't show in editor.

```
<script>
      $(function() {
          $('#PostDesc').froalaEditor({
              imageButtons: ["removeImage", "replaceImage", "linkImage"],
              borderColor: '#00008b',
              imageUploadURL: '@Url.Action("FroalaUploadImage", "Posts")',
              imageParams: { postId: "123" },
              enableScript: false,
              fileUploadURL: '@Url.Action("FroalaUploadFile", "Posts")',
              fileUploadParams: { postId: "123" }
          });
      });
</script>
```

**Action:**

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult FroalaUploadImage(HttpPostedFileBase file, int? postId)
{
    var fileName = Path.GetFileName(file.FileName);
    var rootPath = Server.MapPath("~/img/Post/");
    file.SaveAs(Path.Combine(rootPath, fileName));
    return Json(new { link = "img/Post/" + fileName }, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
}
```

What is wrong in `return Json(new { link = "img/Post/" + fileName }, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);`?

**Update:**

I use this editor in an area and It seams that i must change url.

I wrote

```
return Json(new UrlHelper(this.Request.RequestContext).Content("~/img/Post/" + fileName ), JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
```

instead of

```
return Json(new { link = "img/Post/" + fileName }, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
```

but problem not solved yet!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the problem.

Must wrote

```
return Json(new { link = new UrlHelper(Request.RequestContext).Content("~/img/Post/" + fileName) }, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
```